# A closure operation on subsets of ${\Bbb Z}[x]$

Tags: nt.number-theory, gn.general-topology

Given a(n infinite) set $S\subset {\Bbb Z}[x]$ (integer polynomials), write $R_S$ for the topological closure of the set of all complex roots of all $p\in S$.  Then write $\hat{S}$ for the set of all integer polynomials $q$ such that $q$ has all its roots in $R_S$.

Can one (nicely) characterize $\hat{S}$ in terms of $S$?  Sorry to be vague, but a nice characterization for me should stay in the domain of integer arithmetic, so express itself in terms of polynomial coefficients without an appeal to the complex numbers.  (Perhaps someone knows a paradigm that allows me to ask this more objectively?)

Comment: What has come up in various places is that one associates with a polynomial the probability measure on $\mathbb C$, which is equidistributed on the roots of the polynomial. Now, the space of probability measures has a natural topology and limit points are usually very interesting and special; there are isolated points etc. Equilibrium measures of compact subsets arise this way.

Comment: Do you have an idea of the answer for the (probably simpler) case of polynomials over $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: @Jérôme A special case of your suggestion amounts to finding the degree 1 polynomials in "closure," which just means finding the points  x  lying in the topological closure of all the roots.  Off the top of my head I guess that to identify such $x$ one might consider whether the set $\{ f(x)/f'(x) | f \in S\}$ has $0$ as a limit point, or at least something like that. 